# Dynamic arrays: Access Violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I need to input a dynamic array manually or generate random values.

I definitely did something wrong in "getManual" and "getRandom" functions which keeps crashing the programm and may be related to passing dynamic arrays into functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void getManual(int** arr, int rows, int columns);
void getRandom(int** arr, int rows, int columns);

void main() {
    int rowCount = 5;
    int colCount = 6;

    int** arr = new int* [rowCount];

    cout << " Array formation algorithm\n";
        start:
    cout << "Input number : \n1 for manual\n2 for random\n";
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    switch (k) {
    case 1: getManual(arr, rowCount, colCount);
        break;
    case 2: getRandom(arr, rowCount, colCount);
        break;
    default:cout << "Input 1 or 2, please.";
        cout << endl << endl;
        goto start;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[colCount];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) { //очищуємо память для кожного рядка
        delete[] arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;
}

void getManual(int** arr, int rows, int columns) { //введення з клавіатури
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]=";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
            //cin >> *(*(arr + i) + j); //вказівникова форма
        }
    }
}

void getRandom(int** arr, int rows, int columns) { //випадкова генерація чисел
    int lowest = -21, highest = 34;
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    // ініціалізація масива
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = lowest + rand() % (highest - lowest + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of debugging details:
[Exception unhadled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbSOe.png)

Comment: That sounds like an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Since this is C++ for your own sake stay away from `new[]` and use `std::vector` instead. Lots of these fussy pointer problems will disappear. Use references instead.

Comment: When you get a number like CDCDCDCD that's just too regular check against a [good list of debugging codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values) to see if the program's trying to tell you something.

Comment: @tadman using `new[]` is stated in the condition of the task which was given to me in the university

Comment: You're using `arr` before you've allocated all the space. You allocated the pointers, but not what the pointers point to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `new[]` loop is suppose to be done before you pass it into the function, or else they're uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

> Fred Larson has mentioned this in the comments of your post.

## You are dereferencing garbage pointers

The issue that we see here is the fact that you are not allocating the memory you are accessing.

`int** arr = new int* [rowCount];`

This code above allocates an array of pointers, none of which are being set to anything until *after* you have already accessed this garbage data.

So after quick inspection, moving this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
     arr[i] = new int[colCount];
}
```

to right after: `int** arr = new int* [rowCount];` should fix the stated problem.

```
int** arr = new int* [rowCount]; // allocate pointers

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
     arr[i] = new int[colCount]; // allocate the data portion for the pointers
}
```